# PHP view/edit displayed data

Tags: php

Hello I am new to PHP and I have a feedback form that students fill out and when an admin logs in they get to view and edit their data, in my codes, I cant fetch the old data input by the students so the inputs are empty even though if I fill it in my self it does get updated.

view.php page:

```
<?php 
include "includes/database.php";
?>

<?php 
$query=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `feedback`");
if($query){
    echo "here ug o";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
?>
  
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
     <table class="table table-hover">
          <tr>
          <th>id</th>
              <th>oopr</th>
              <th>oopc</th>

              <th>webr</th>
              <th>webc</th>

              <th>databasec</th>
              <th>databasec</th>

              <th>networkc</th>
              <th>networkc</th>

              <th>logicc</th>
              <th>logicc</th>
            </tr>
          <tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
               
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["fid"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['oopR']; ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo $row['oopC']; ?></td> 

              <td><?php echo $row['webR']; ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo $row['webC']; ?></td> 

              <td><?php echo $row['databaseR']; ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo $row['databaseC']; ?></td> 

              <td><?php echo $row['networkR']; ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo $row['networkC']; ?></td> 

              <td><?php echo $row['logicR']; ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo $row['logicC']; ?></td>
              <td><a href="edit.php?fid=<?php echo $row['fid']; ?>">Update</a></td> 
              </tr>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
                
              </tr>
       </table>
<?php 
} 
?>
</div>
```

edit.php page WHERE I HAVE THE ISSUES.(i tried to add value to the inputs but it didn't work that's why I erased it):

```
<?php 
include "includes/database.php";
?>

<?php 

$fid = $_GET['fid'];
$query=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `feedback` WHERE `fid`= '$fid' ");
?>
  

  <div class="container d-flex h-100 mr-4 p-4" >
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
          <form method="POST" name="form" action="editprocess.php"> 
            <div class="form-group">
              <h1>OOP</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">rating</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="oopr">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="oopc" value="<?php echo $oopc;?>"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>Web</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">rating</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="webr">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="webc"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>Database</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">rating</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="databaser">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="databasec"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>Network</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">rating</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="networkr">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="networkc"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>logic</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">rating</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="logicr">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="logicc"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="fid" value=<?php echo $_GET['fid'];?>>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit">submit feedback</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

editprocess.php page:

```
<?php 
include "includes/database.php";
?>
<?php 
include "includes/database.php";
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $oopr= $_POST['oopr'];
    $oopc= $_POST['oopc'];

    $webr= $_POST['webr'];
    $webc= $_POST['webc'];
    
    $databaser= $_POST['databaser'];
    $databasec= $_POST['databasec'];
    
    $networkr= $_POST['networkr'];
    $networkc= $_POST['networkc'];
    
    $logicr= $_POST['logicr'];
    $logicc= $_POST['logicc'];
    $fid=$_POST['fid'];

    $query= mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `feedback` 
                SET `oopR`='$oopr' , `oopC` ='$oopc', `webR`='$webr', 
                    `webC`='$webc', `databaseR`='$databaser', 
                    `databaseC`='$databasec', `networkR` 
                    ='$networkr',`networkC`='$networkc', `logicR`='$logicr', 
                    `logicC`='$logicc'  WHERE fid=$fid ");
}
?>
```

Comment: *"I cant fetch the old data"* - Why can't you?  What is the specific error or problem that you observe?

Comment: no errors, the sql result is just empty. on the view page when I click on the edit button on the row that I want to edit, an empty form opens instead of a form with the data input by the user.

Comment: If `SELECT * FROM feedback` produces no results then that table is empty.  When you run that same query manually on your database, outside of PHP entirely, does that table contain records?  How have you confirmed that there's any data in that table at all?  Where do you ever insert data into that table?  How have you confirmed that operation is working?  Please debug and narrow down the problem.

Comment: the SELECT * FROM feedback works. the  "SELECT * FROM `feedback` WHERE `fid`= '$fid' " doesnt work.

Comment: And when you debug, what is the exact SQL query you're executing in that case?  (The runtime value of `$fid` and the resulting runtime value of the string you're building with it?)  When you execute *that* query manually on the database, are any results returned?  What have you done to confirm that there are matching records in the data?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: You `mysqli_fetch_array(...)` in `view.php` but don't in `edit.php`?

Comment: Why `include "includes/database.php";` twice in `editprocess.php`?

Comment: @sarah: In `edit.php`, where do you ever use the value of `$query`?  How do you observe that the query returns no results when you never use the results of the query?

Comment: i have a table that contains all the feedback its called by this query SELECT * FROM feedback in my "view" page. in that page I have an edit button next to each row. when I click the edit button instead of a form with the user input data it shows an empty form. however when I fill out the form it does get edited and shows the edited version on my "view" page. @David

Comment: @sarah: *"instead of a form with the user input data it shows an empty form"* - Nowhere in `edit.php` do you use the results of the query to set values in the form inputs.  Why specifically do you expect values to be shown there?  Please be very specific.  Don't just say "it doesn't work", but focus on a *specific* operation.  For example, a specific value you are trying to output which isn't outputting as expected.  What very specific thing are you observing as an example and what are you expecting?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Unrelated fyi: a `<textarea>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. You place its content between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`

Comment: Related to above `<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="oopc" value="<?php echo $oopc;?>"></textarea>` Where is `$oopc` supposed to come from anyway

Comment: iam expecting that when UPDATE button is clicked (which is placed next to each record) in the view page,it takes me to edit page where a form opens that lets me change the user input data. what is not working is : the form that opens is empty and does not contain data even though it is showing in the view.php page. @David

Comment: that is where i have my issue, I have tried to fetch the data by $fid = $_GET['fid']; and add values to the inputs. but it results empty @RiggsFolly

Comment: @sarah: Once again, the form is empty because you don't populate it with any data.  Regardless of your expectations, the code is not going to guess what you want it to do and do it for you.  For any given form input on the edit page, if you want a value to be pre-populated into that form input then you need to output that value in your code.  (As a `value` attribute for `<input>` elements, as content for `<textarea>` elements, as a `selected` attribute on `<option>` elements, etc.)  Look at the code in your `edit.php` page.  ***You never use the results of the query.***

Answer (score 1):

In your `edit.php` code

Problem 1: You are querying the database but never fetching the result row from the resultset

Problem 2: You are using code that is vulnereable to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) so I have amended to use a prepared query

Problem 3: You are attempting to place the data into a `value` attribute on a `<textarea>` and there is no such attribute on a `<textarea>` element. The data goes between the start and end tag `<textarea>SO data goes in here</textarea>`

```
<?php 
include "includes/database.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `feedback` WHERE `fid`= ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['fid']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Now you can use the columns name in your html to pre fill the feedback info but as per Problem 3, place the values in the correct place in the HTML

```
  <div class="container d-flex h-100 mr-4 p-4" >
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
          <form method="POST" name="form" action="editprocess.php"> 
            <div class="form-group">
              <h1>OOP</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">rating</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="oopr">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="oopc">
                    <?php echo $oopc;?>
                </textarea>
            </div>
```

Note where the `<?php echo $oopc;?>` is now. So keep going with that for all the other sections

> You also shoudl check that the `$_GET['fid']` actually exists before attempting to use it so look up [`isset()` in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)